# Counting Distinct Characters in an Array

Tags: vb.net

I have seen various threads similar to this one, but none really suit my specific needs. I have an assignment due at the end of the week that I think I am close to completing, but can't seem to find my error in my code. The instructions are to take a user input sentence, phrase or word and count the number of occurrences of each letter and output the letter and the number of occurrences to the screen. I can get the distinct letters from any given string, however I can't seem to make the number of occurrences count accurately. I keep ending up with either the index of the letter in the string, 1 or as this snippet shows, a random number.

```
Sub charCount()

    'Declare variables
    Dim UserPhrase As String = input.Text
    Dim charArray() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Alphabet.txt")
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim UserArray() As Char = UserPhrase.ToCharArray()

    'Find each letter in the string
    Dim letterQuery = From letter In charArray
                      Select letter

    'Count number of occurrences of each letter
    For Each letter In letterQuery
        If UserArray.Contains(letter) Then
            For Each c As Char In UserArray
                count = count + 1
            Next
            output.Items.Add(letter & "    " & count)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here I have added comments:

```
'Count number of occurrences of each letter
For Each letter In letterQuery
    If UserArray.Contains(letter) Then
        For Each c As Char In UserArray
            'here you should add comparing c to letter. If equal then increment
            count = count + 1
        Next
        output.Items.Add(letter & "    " & count)
        'here you should reset counter to 0
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much, comparing the c to letter was exactly what I was missing!

Answer (score -1):

I honestly don't know what you're trying to do there, but this is as trivial as the following:

```
var count = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").SelectMany(s=>s).Distinct().Count();
```